# ...the outside of no door

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

The following quote is from "Mansfield Park" by Jane Austen:

Fanny was just beginning to collect herself, and to feel that if she stayed longer behind it might seem disrespectful, when this point was settled, and being commissioned with the brother and sister's apology, saw them preparing to go as she quitted the room herself to perform the dreadful duty of appearing before her uncle.
Too soon did she find herself at the drawing-room door; and after pausing a moment for what she knew would not come, for a courage **which the outside of no door** had ever supplied to her, she turned the lock in desperation, and the lights of the drawing-room, and all the collected family, were before her.

I wonder what the part in bold "which the outside of no door" means.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the outside of **the** door = the side of the door from which one would enter the room, i.e. the side facing her.

Doors have a relative "inside" and "outside": the inside is the side that you see when you are inside the room, and the outside is the side that you see when you are on the outside of the room,

Compare:

Too soon did she find herself at the drawing-room door; and after pausing a moment for what she knew would not come, for a courage which **no side of any door** had ever supplied to her, she turned the lock in desperation,

She is saying that although she waited for courage at the outside of the door, the side of a door had never given her any courage.

She refines this by saying "the ***out**side* of the door" -a courage which **no outside of any door** had ever supplied to her"

Comment: Thanks a lot.  very helpful.

Answer (score 3):

Again, it's a form of expression which is not common now, and I'm not sure it was even in Austen's time.

To help understand it, note that you can usually recast a sentence containing *no/not
... ever* into one with *never*.

So

> a courage which the outside of no door had ever supplied to her

is the same as

> a courage which the outside of any door had never supplied to her

In more normal language it might be

> courage which she had never found when waiting to go through any door

suggesting that she was often nervous standing outside a door she was expected to go through.